# Make an action on every new file in directory

Tags: file-handling

I have a directory with 14.000 files. 20-50 files will be added everyday to this directory.

I want to perform an action on all new files placed in this directory and I only want this action to be performed once per file.

I aldready made a rutine and it works but it really sucks.

It goes like this:

1. Get all files in direcroty to a Listbox
2. Load textfile with all processed files to another Listbox
3. Compare Listboxes and extract all new files.
4. Perform action on the new files.
5. Save textfile with all processed files.

This is the code for no. 3:

```
for i := 0 to FileListDir.Items.Count - 1 do
  if FileListHandled.Items.IndexOf(FileListDir.Items[i]) = -1 then
     FilesNeedHandling.Items.Add(FileListDir.Items[i]);
```

The rutine takes about 30-35 seconds to complete.

2 Questions:

1. How can I make my rutine faster ?
2. It is possible to get only the "new" files in the directory without using my rutine.

Answer (score 0):

"find" command can be used for this.

```
find <path of directory> -mtime -1 -print
```

This prints files modified under the given directory within the past one day

```
find <path of directory> -mtime -1 -exec <command> {} \;
```

This finds the files modified within the past day and  runs the given command on each of the files

```
find <path of directory> -mmin -60 -exec <command> {} \;
```

This handles files modified within the last 60 minutes.

Comment: I have had that thought.

Comment: If you run this, say once every hour, you can find all the files modified in the last 60 minutes by the option `-mmin -60`. I think that should cover all files.

Comment: If program crashes over a weekend, there will be a time gap, and there will also be a risk that files will be processed more than once (thats why I saved processed filenames to a textfile)

Comment: Assuming you are using python, `list(set(FileListDir.Items) - set(FileListHandled.Items))` should give the list of files not processed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is not Phyton but Delphi (the tag was removed?)

I had to rethink it all, again. And this time I sucseeded.

I wrote my own rutine to load files into a listbox and made a bubble sort on it.
After that I could extract the filenames not handled.

Test scenario: 4628 Files

Test profiling goes like this:

Load filelist into:
TFileListBox        Time:  2,24
TFileListBoxEx      Time:  1,52
TJvFileListBox      Time: 59,28 (Wtf is wrong with the Jvl libralies?)

Own rutine to load files with datetime info and bubble sort into:
TListBox            Time:  1,61

```
 // Get files list
  if FindFirst(C_MailIncomingDir+'\*.eml', faAnyFile, Rec) = 0 then
  repeat
    Setlength(FileList, Length(FileList) + 1);
    Setlength(DateList, Length(DateList) + 1);
    FileList[High(FileList)]:= Rec.Name;
    DateList[High(DateList)]:= FileDateToDateTime(Rec.Time);
  until FindNext(Rec) <> 0;
  FindClose(Rec);

  // Sort
  // Bubble sort
  repeat
    Done:= True;
    for i:= 0 to High(FileList) - 1 do
      if DateList[i] > DateList[i + 1] then
      begin
        Done:= False;
        TempName:= FileList[i];
        FileList[i]:= FileList[i + 1];
        FileList[i + 1]:= TempName;

        TempDate:= DateList[i];
        DateList[i]:= DateList[i + 1];
        DateList[i + 1]:= TempDate;
      end;
  until Done;

  // Show in list
  FilesInDir.Clear;
  for i:= 0 to High(FileList) do
    FilesInDir.Items.Add(FileList[i] + '   ' + DateTimeToStr(DateList[i]));
```

By sorting the files by datetime, it is possible to diff out all files not already handled with this line (0,06 instead of 10 secs for 4500 files):

```
for I := FileListHandled.Count to FilesInDir.Count-1 do
   FilesNeedHandling.Items.Add(FilesInDir.Items[i]);
```